# Concatenate binary representation of two ints

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Let's say we have two int variables, `A` and `B` of bit length `N < 16` and `M < 16` respectively.
We want to have a new int variable `C` such that the `N` lowest bits contain the bits of `A` and the next `M` bits contain the bits of `B`. (Assuming all variables are 32 bits long and little endian).

In my solution I slightly cheated by using binary strings instead:

```
int a = 65535;
int b = 65;
String cStr = Integer.toBinaryString(b) + Integer.toBinaryString(a);
int c = Integer.parseInt(cStr, 2);
```

But, how do I do it using bitwise operators?

Examples:

`A=1, B=1 (N=1, M=1 resp.) then C = 11
 A = 11000011010100, B = 101100 (N=14, M=6 resp.) then C = 10110011000011010100`

Comment: OK, so do you really want to only consider bits set a 1s? This means you won't be able to get a and b back out as you won't know where the boundary is.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest you to improve your question by providing also the expected output. I am not entirely sure that your code solves what you describe in words (e.g. there is no `N` or `M`). Also, it would be much more beneficial to you if you could show a solution where you try to use bitwise operators.

Comment: is it correct that, assuming both `a`  and `b` are `1` (one), you want the result to be `3` (three)??

Comment: @norok2 hi! added the examples as suggested

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java:

```
c = b << 16 | a;
```

But if you want to shift by the exact number of bits:

```
c = b << (32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(a)) | a;
```

Comment: `Integer.highestOneBit()` does not return the position of the highest bit set in the passed parameter. Read the docs carefully. For instance, passing 20 as a parameter, it returns 16 and not 4.

Comment: Yep - I fixed it before you finished your comment. Sorry for the initial mistake.

Comment: The second solution is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Note that due to the way, the shift operator works, you don’t need to specify the `32`, i.e. you can simply use `c = b << - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(a) | a;`

Answer (score -1):

try this and check if you have the same value. I am not sure how it will be in java, but this work for C++ and C# 
int c = b << 16 | a;

first you should calculate how much to shift b. so:

```
int a = 65535;
int count = 0;
int temp = a;
while(temp != 0)
{
  ++count;
  temp = temp >> 1;
}

int b = 65;
int c = b << count | a;
```

Comment: It's understandable that you can't comment because of your low reputation, but, that is clearly not a reason to use an answer as comment, like everybody else, you'll need to wait until you get enough reputation to do it, you may delete this post, Thanks.

Comment: This always reserves 16 bits for the value of A. It should concatenate the bits, also in case A occupies less then 16 bits.